# jQuery Modal window will not load

Tags: jquery, html, dom, overlay, modal-dialog

I am working on a wordpress site and I need some overlay windows. They pop up fine when I am working locally but for some reason when I put my changes on the live server the window will not pop up. Anyone know why this is?

The word "Aristokraft" in the sidebar of this page should trigger the window: http://friendlumber.com.s111208.gridserver.com/kitchens-and-baths/kitchens/cabinets

--html--

```
<div id="popup_name" class="popup_block">
    <div id="image"><img src="img/doorbig.jpg" border="0"/></div> 
        <div id="gallery-shell">
        <a href="#" rel="img/doorbig.jpg" class="image"><img src="img/doorthumb.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a> 
        <a href="#" rel="img/doorbig.jpg" class="image"><img src="img/doorthumb.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a> 
        <a href="#" rel="img/doorbig.jpg" class="image"><img src="img/doorthumb.jpg" class="thumb" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

--trigger html--

```
<li><a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" class="poplight">Aristokraft</a></li>
```

--script--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Code goes here



    //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( 900 ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="img/cancel.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 

    return false;
});

//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
    });
    return false;
});




});
```

Comment: where is your `document.ready(...);` in your live server? Double check. It is not being included

Comment: now ur site is working correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.poplight').click(function()
```

Change your selecter like this and try it

Comment: Ok tryed that, works locally but still does not work on the liver server. so weird.

Comment: Did you added jquery script files to the live server correctly? check the paths of jquery files.